# Get closest tr inside function js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this js code :

```
$(".contenteditable").keyup(function(){
    var data = $(this).text();
    var domId = document.activeElement.id;
    var userId = $(this).closest('tr').find('[type="hidden"]:first').val();
    $.post
    (
        "/users/"+userId,
        {
            data,domId,userId,'_method':'patch'
        },
        function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    )
});
```

Its working ok. However, now I want to make it as function and use it for any page I tried like this:

```
function keyUpUpdate()
{
  var data = document.activeElement.textContent;
  var domId = document.activeElement.id;
  var userId = $(this).closest('tr').find('[type="hidden"]:first').val();

  console.log(userId);
}
```

The `userId` is not working inside this function. 
How can I get the closest `tr` and then the first input type hidden value from the active element inside function.

Comment: show html and what error in the console

Comment: please should show us how you call "keyUpUpdate()" because maybe you have a problem in the context (this object)

Comment: undefined this is the error inside the console

Comment: $(".contenteditable").keyup(function(){
 keyUpUpdate();
});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` has no context inside your function you should send the current object to the `keyUpUpdate()` as parameter then get `userId` based on this object :

```
$(".contenteditable").keyup(function(){
    keyUpUpdate($(this));

    //Other code
})

function keyUpUpdate(_this)
{
    var data = document.activeElement.textContent;
    var domId = document.activeElement.id;
    var userId = $(_this).closest('tr').find('[type="hidden"]:first').val();
    console.log(userId);
}
```

Or if you've just this function to execute on `keyup` you could call it directly then the `this` object will be passed dynamically :

```
$(".contenteditable").keyup(keyUpUpdate);

function keyUpUpdate()
{
    var data = document.activeElement.textContent;
    var domId = document.activeElement.id;
    var userId = $(this).closest('tr').find('[type="hidden"]:first').val();

    console.log(userId);
}
```

Hope this helps.